# Install Office 2010 Standard on another laptop

Tags: microsoft-office, transfer, software-activation

I want to transfer my Office 2010 installation to another laptop. Do I have to inform Microsoft about the transfer so that it is activated correctly on the new laptop?

In the license agreement it is said that I can install Office 2010 on a portable computer without uninstalling it on the primary computer (licensed device). But I'm not sure the activation service is adapted according to these terms. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem with this.  I'd certainly install it on the new laptop before removing it from the old.

Typically, if it's been a few months since you last installed Office, it'll activate normally over the internet.  Worst case, you might have to call in and talk to someone to get it activated.